# How to find the recently deleted questions in some section?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Today an user (I can't remember his username) have posted two interesting questions in the Commutative Algebra section, but these were not very well formulated, so he got few downvotes. Then he deleted the questions and I wonder how can I find (if possible!) these questions?

**Edit.** Maybe this helps: one was about the Rees algebra of an ideal, while the other one was about the edge ideal of a graph.

Comment: The approach suggested [in this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8564/) can be used to find recent deleted posts. However, it might be a lot of work. (Unless the post was very recent, so you have good bounds for the id of the post.)

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/428680/8581) is another one that I could just vote it to undelete. I can't ask her why did she delete it. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way, because self-deletions are not listed in the "recently deleted" section of either the 10k+ or the moderator tools. However, by googling things like "math stack commutative algebra" with the results restricted to the past 24 hours, I found one question with negative score that had been deleted, and then knowing the user name, googled "math stack algebra <user name>" to find the other one. Presumably these are the ones you're thinking of?

- [Property of an edge ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428473/264)
- [Rees algebra of a monomial ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428272/264)

Another approach would be to go through one's browser history (though since I didn't go to these pages before this wasn't an option for me).

Comment: Yes, sure, thank you!